# python printing dictionary to csv gives blank file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am using the following code as a representation of a larger dictionary which needs to be printed to a csv file:

```
import csv
dict1 = {"hello": 1}
w = csv.writer(open("C:\output.csv", "w"))
for key, val in dict1.items():
    w.writerow([key, val])
```

But the `output.csv` is blank. What am I missing?

Comment: You aren't closing the file, so it probably isn't getting flushed to disk. Alternatively, use a context manager: `with open(...) as ...`.

Comment: Your example works on my system. Try closing the file to ensure that behavior elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files you open need to be closed. Inside a `with` block, that happens automatically, for example:

```
import csv
dict1 = {"hello": "world"}
with open("C:\output.csv", "w") as fd:
    w = csv.writer(fd)
    for key, val in dict1.items():
        w.writerow([key, val])
```

Comment: w = csvwrite(fd) will cause only the last [key, value] to overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. For me it works, not just in this example, but also with two key/value pairs that both do get written.